# xPath inside xPath?

Tags: javascript, xml, xpath, soap

This xml below retrieve results from a query and have an embedded XML document of responseText element.

```
    <resultsResponse>
    <errors/>
    <responseformat>xml</responseformat>
    <responseText><![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><records><record><slice><![CDATA[40224]]]]>><![CDATA[</slice></record><record><slice><![CDATA[40224]]]]>><![CDATA[</slice></record><record><slice><![CDATA[40224]]]]>><![CDATA[</slice></record></records>]]>      
    </responseText>
    </resultsResponse>
```

I want to get slice attribute, but i don't know exactly how can do that without make two xpaths separately.

Any chance to get slice information using only one xpath query? Like turn responseText into a node tree?

What I'm doing now: use a xPath Query to get the responseText attribute: //responseText. It returns:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <records><record><slice><![CDATA[40224]]></slice></record><record><slice><![CDATA[40224]]></slice></record><record><slice><![CDATA[40224]]></slice></record></records>
```

after i have to keep this new xml inside of a variable and apply another xPath Query to get slice elements: //slice

```
40224
40224
40224
```

The problem is: Is mandatory to use xPath query just one time and without code (just using xPath expressions).

Comment: The purpose of a CDATA element is to contain data that isn't meant to be parsed as XML. Why do you want to avoid using two separate XPaths?

Comment: I'm using resources of an existing and without code application (a SaaS chatbot). Unfortunately I'm not able to save the first xPath result on another XML Document and do a new query. I must do this using one xPath query only.

Comment: _"Any chance to get slice information using only one xpath query? Like turn responseText into a node tree?"_ Only in XPath 3.0+ like `parse-xml(/resultsResponse/responseText)//slice` [Test](http://xpatheval.apphb.com/898ovfI7y)